# trouble Initializing Boolean array with true

Tags: c++, boolean, c++14

I am trying to understand how can I initialize a bool array, I tried using memset and it worked but, when I tried to initialize it directly I failed.

```
bool prime[n+1] ;
memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
```

-- this works.

but the following doesn't.

```
bool prime[n+1] = {1};
//memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
```

I've tried the following too.

```
bool prime[n+1] = {1};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value)

Comment: In case n in your sample is a variable and not a constant this isn't really "legal" c++ in terms of following the c++ standard. Array initialization based on a variable only works on some compilers or in some cases only with compiler extensions so you should probably avoid doing that. If you want a dynamic array use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 4):

It does initialize your array. This is how [brace-enclosed initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_brace-enclosed_lists) works. The first array element is initialized to `1`, which translates to `true`, and all other elements are initialized to `0` which translates to `false`. This:

```
bool v[10] = { 1 };
```

is the same as if you had:

```
bool v[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

You can use the [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function and friends:

```
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), true);
std::fill_n(v, 10, true);
```

Comment: To not rely on magic numbers: `std::fill(v, std::end(v), true);`

Comment: @eerorika for symmetry: `std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), true);`

Answer (score 1):

Initializing an array like this:

```
bool foo[10] = {1};  // initialize only the first element to 1, the rest get 0.
```

You need to use the memset approach, or else provide n values in your initializer list

```
bool foo[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

Or use std::fill, a loop, or any other way to set all the values.